# Convert Prototype script to jquery

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

I have this function I found in an article somewhere that seems to mix prototype with jquery scripts, but I don't want to include prototype as it breaks everything else. So I wanted to see if anyone out there could help convert this to jQuery for me.

The function is supposed to detect if the browser auto-filled out form fields and set a class to their label accordingly.

```
$("label.placeholder + .input-text").each(function (type) {
Event.observe(window, 'load', function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (!input.value.empty()) {
            input.previous().addClassName('has-text');
        }
    }, 200);
});
});
```

The problem is I keep getting the error `Event.observe is not a function`.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: this won't work.. where is input defined and why should an `onload` observer be in each iteration? is this everything you've got from the code?

Answer (score 1):

If what you're doing is checking for cached-values onload, then you could try this:

```
$(window).load(function(e){

setTimeout(function(t){
  $('label.placeholder + .input-text').each(function(index, element){
    if (!$(element).val())
    {
      $(element).prev().addClass('has-text');
    }
  });
}, 200);

});
```

It should remove the excessive number of calls to setTimeout.

you may be able to change the first line to: `jQuery(function($){`, but I'm not sure if the auto-filled forms will have loaded after the `document.onready` event or the `window.onload` event.  You'll just have to play with it to find out.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I can't seem to get it to work quite the way I want it to. It's not so much about auto-filling on the document load but rather about when the user starts filling out the form and their browser auto-completes the rest of the form (example, starts typing in first name, chooses from their browser's auto-fill and the rest of the fields become filled out)

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help:

```
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("label.placeholder + .input-text").each(function() {
      if ($(this).val()) $(this).prev().addClass('has-text');
    });
  }, 200);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I can't seem to get it to work quite the way I want it to. See my reply above for what I'm going for

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I figured it out... might not be the best way to do it but it works! Here's my new code:

```
$("label.placeholder + .input-text").each(function (type) {

  // Check if anything is filled in on page load
  if( $(this).val() !== '') {
    $(this).prev("label.placeholder").addClass("has-text").removeClass("focus");
  } else {
    $(this).prev("label.placeholder").removeClass("has-text").removeClass("focus");
  }

  //Change the label style
  $(this).focus(function () {
    $(this).prev("label.placeholder").addClass("focus");
  });

  //Check if user has typed anything in the field
  $(this).keyup(function () {
    $(this).prev("label.placeholder").addClass("has-text").removeClass("focus");
  });

  //
  $(this).blur(function () {

    // Loops through all fields to see if the browser has auto-filled after the user inputted something
    setTimeout(function(t){
      $('label.placeholder + .input-text').each(function(index, element){
        if( $(element).val() !== '') {
          $(this).prev("label.placeholder").addClass("has-text").removeClass("focus");
        }
      });
    }, 200);

    // If the field is left blank, set the label back to default
    if($(this).val() === "") {
      $(this).prev("label.placeholder").removeClass("has-text").removeClass("focus");
    } else {
      $(this).prev("label.placeholder").addClass("has-text").removeClass("focus");
    }
});
```

The question is, should I do the check through all fields to see if the have a value on `$(this).blur` or on `$(this).keyup` ?

Thanks again for your help and suggestions!